# Как сделать так, что если парсер не может опустится ниже, он заканчивает функцию?

Tags: python, асинхронность, playwright

```
            for (index, elem) in enumerate(list_of_categories):
                async with async_playwright() as p:
                    url = elem
                    browser = await p.firefox.launch(headless=False)
                    page = await browser.new_page()
                    await page.goto(url)
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)
                    await page.click(".pointer.help-city__btn.btn.btn-large.btn-primary")
                    await asyncio.sleep(1)

                    while True:
                        try:
                            while await page.locator("#newBtnPager").is_visible() is False:
                                await page.mouse.wheel(0, 300)
                                await browser.set_page_load_timeout(120)

                            while await page.locator("#newBtnPager").is_visible() is True:
                                await page.click("#newBtnPager")
                                categories_with_medicines_1 = (
                                    await page.query_selector_all(".product-hor.mb-10.js-stateProduct"))
                                await browser.close()
                            break
                        except Exception as err:
                            print(err)
                            break
```